# Объединение нескольких html в Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Как объединить несколько html файлов в Thymeleaf?
Я реализовывал данный код через php с помощью `include_once "header.html";`, но в thymeleaf подобной конструкции не нашел.

У меня есть 3 файла: header.html, main.html, footer.html. Надо вставить файлы header и footer в main.

header.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Общая информация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../css/account_css.css}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/ajax-change.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="include/navigation.html :: nav"></nav>


<div class="top-part">
    <span class="top-part-title">Dashboard</span>
    <span class="top-part-description">2500+ рецептов</span>
</div>
<div class="main-split">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div>
            <a href="" class="current-tab" data-target="general">Общая информация</a>
            <a href="" data-target="notifications">Настройка увидомлений</a>
            <a href="">Ваша следующая доставка</a>
            <a href="">Ваша продуктовая корзина</a>
            <a href="">История покупок</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

main.html:

```
<div class="right-side">
        <span class="rs-account-name" th:text="${'Добро пожаловать, ' + user.name + user.surname}"></span>

        <!-- Личная информация -->
        <div class="rs-block">
            <div class="rs-block-top">
                <span class="rs-block-title">Личная информация</span>
                <span class="rs-edit">Редактировать</span>
            </div>


            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Name:</span>
                <span th:text="${user.name + user.surname}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Email:</span>
                <span th:text="${user.email}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Telephone 1:</span>
                <span th:text="${user.phoneNumber1}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Telephone 2:</span>
                <span th:text="${user.phoneNumber2}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main personal-code">
                <span>Личный код:</span>
                <span th:text="${user.id}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Адрее -->
        <div class="rs-block">
            <div class="rs-block-top">
                <span class="rs-block-title">Адрес</span>
                <span class="rs-edit">Редактировать</span>
            </div>


            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Address line 1:</span>
                <span>Pikk tn 78</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Address line 2:</span>
                <span>Vanalinn</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Address line 3:</span>
                <span>Loster 20</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>City:</span>
                <span>Tallinn</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rs-block-main">
                <span>Post code:</span>
                <span th:text="${user.postcode}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

footer.html (футор будет еще доделан):

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А чем директива replace не устраивает?

Comment: @RomanC судя по коду, потребуется использовать 4 replace...

Comment: Я вот думаю, можно ли как-то добавить main в единый файл header-footer (заменяя только класс `right-side`)? вместо того, чтобы собирать два файла в main?

Я понимаю, что можно, но как тогда прописать команду, что зависимо от страницы, показывать разные дивы с классом `right-side`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оффтопик:
Искал неделю ответ и в итоге не нашел лучше, чем просто использовать `th:replace`.
Уверен, что мое решение это костыль, но зато работает.

Идея такова: создаем файл, в котором будет `header` и `footer` (назовем его **файл-шаблон**), а пространтво между ними, которое будет `<div>`, будет изменяться в зависимости от того, на какой странице нахожусь.

Как выглядит **файл-шаблон**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Общая информация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../css/account_css.css}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="include/navigation.html :: nav"></nav>

<div class="top-part">
    <span class="top-part-title">Dashboard</span>
    <span class="top-part-description">2500+ рецептов</span>
</div>
<div class="main-split">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div>
            <a href="/account/general"data-target="general">Общая информация</a>
            <a href="/account/notifications" data-target="notifications">Настройка увидомлений</a>
            <a href="">Ваша следующая доставка</a>
            <a href="">Ваша продуктовая корзина</a>
            <a href="">История доставок</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- здесь заканчивается header -->

    <div style="width: 60%;" th:if="${status} eq 'general'" th:insert="~{account/include/general.html :: div}"></div>
    <div style="width: 60%;" th:if="${status} eq 'notifications'" th:insert="~{account/include/notifications.html :: div}"></div>

<!-- здесь начинается footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как выглядит, допустим, `general.html`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="right-side">
   <span class="rs-account-name">Имя Фамилия</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[`th:replace`](https://anshulgnit.blogspot.com/2018/05/difference-between-thymeleaf-attribute-replace-insert-and-include.html) нужен нам для "вставки кода из другого файла".
`th:if` - это условие (логично). В зависимости от двух возможных исходов событий, див, с даннным условием, либо будет показываться, либо нет. То есть, если я захочу загрузить `/account/general`, status у меня будет иметь значение `general` (об этом я расскажу дальше), то из данных двух дивов с условиями значение `true` будет только у дива с `th:if="${status} eq 'general'"`.

Переходим к контроллеру страницы. Вот как я его реализовал (я знаю, что у меня есть дубликация кода, но я не знаю как от нее избавиться.):

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/account/general")
    public ModelAndView general(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        // Вот он статус. Т.к. эта часть относится к станице general, то
        // и status будет получать значение general
        modelAndView.addObject("status", "general");
        modelAndView.setViewName("account/account");
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/account/notifications")
    public ModelAndView notifications(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        // Вот он статус. Т.к. эта часть относится к станице notifications, то
        // и status будет получать значение notifications
        modelAndView.addObject("status", "notifications");
        modelAndView.setViewName("account/account");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```